# Firefox Web Extension in React, unable to parse CSS - "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type"

Tags: css, reactjs, firefox-addon-webextensions

In my code, I am importing `index.css` with the line `import './index.css';` in my main App file. However, when I try to build the app, I get the following error, even though I know there is not an issue with the CSS file itself:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.css 1:5
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:5)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> body {
|   margin: 0;
|   font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen',
```

Here is my current `webpack.config.js`, I am not sure what is missing from it or what I should add to it:

```
const HTMLPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const ExtensionReloader = require('webpack-extension-reloader');
const ManifestVersionSyncPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-version-sync-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    options: './src/options.js',
    popup: './src/popup.js',
    content: './src/content.js',
    background: './src/background.js',
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css'],
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), 'node_modules'],
    alias: {
      react: 'preact/compat',
      'react-dom': 'preact/compat',
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HTMLPlugin({
      chunks: ['options'],
      filename: 'options.html',
      title: 'Options page title',
    }),
    new HTMLPlugin({
      chunks: ['popup'],
      filename: 'popup.html',
    }),
    new CopyPlugin([
      { from: './src/_locales/', to: './_locales' },
      { from: './src/assets', to: './assets' },
      { from: './src/manifest.json', to: './manifest.json' },
    ]),
    new ExtensionReloader({
      manifest: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/manifest.json'),
    }),
    new ManifestVersionSyncPlugin(),
  ],
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
  },
  mode: 'production',
  stats: 'minimal',
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your webpack config hasn't been set up to handle `.css` imports. If this is primarily for a `production` only environment, then add these packages:

[mini-css-extract-plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/)

[css-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/)

`npm install -D mini-css-extract-plugin css-loader`

or

`yarn add -D mini-css-extract-plugin css-loader`

Then `require` the mini-css-extract package:

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
```

Add this to your webpack `rules` config after the `.jsx` rule:

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"],
}
```

And lastly, add this to your list of webpack `plugins`:

```
new MiniCssExtractPlugin()
```

The two links above contain more info about custom options and custom setups. I'd recommend giving them a read if you run into any additional CSS-related issues.